# use element ui upload Multiple pictures how to get the picture path store in imgarr arrary

Tags: vue.js, element

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9TkA.png)

the response data such like that, how to store the `res.imgarr`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file-list` data field, which holds the default uploaded files.

Here is the doc: 
http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload

Js Fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/h634yrf5/

Check the console log when you add new file in the attached example and you will notice the list of files.