# passing from an input data as an array of images to the api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to pass from an input multiply images to the api as the following:

```
<el-form-item label="images" prop="images">
  <el-input name="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" v-model="property.images" v-on:input="changed"/>
</el-form-item>
```

and then passing to the data as:

```
  data() {
    return {
      property: { title: '', description: '', price: 0, images []},
```

then passing to api:

```
  createProperty() {
      WebAppAPI.CreateProperty(this.property).then(response => {
```

but is only passing one string url, even though I add several images.

Any idea what else do I need to do to pass an array instead of a string?

Comment: Copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472854/use-element-ui-upload-multiple-pictures-how-to-get-the-picture-path-store-in-img

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this demo fidddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/s8ot36kh/

```
 <el-upload multiple="multiple" class="upload-demo" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" :on-change="handleChange" :file-list="fileList3">
  <el-button size="small" type="primary">Click to upload</el-button>
  <div slot="tip" class="el-upload__tip">jpg/png files with a size less than 500kb</div>
</el-upload>
```